# MacBook Mail Issue

Tags: mac, mail.app, email, gmail

I added an new Gmail account to my Mac OS X Mail app in the Dock and it says it's there except I don't get email from that particular account. I opened up the setting for the email and this image is what shows up. When I check the Mail or Notes check box it immediately changes back to blank. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: you opened the mail-preferences--accounts and used the (+) add email account and filled in the information?

Comment: When i added my email a popup would say "unable to verify account name or password"

Comment: I assume you know those and you can log in on line (web version of gmail), but what did you use for Incoming and outgoing mail server?

Comment: for incoming use "imap.gmail.com" for outgoing use "smtp.gmail.com" in the account type it should say "Google IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Two-Step Verification turned on for your Google account, you will need to log onto your Google account and generate an App Specific Password for your MacBook Mail.

You will find it at https://myaccount.google.com

Then go under Sign-in & Security

Scroll down a little bit and then select App Passwords

At the bottom, there is a select an app dropdown along with a my device dropdown.

Follow the instructions to generate a password, then use that password to log into Gmail from your Mail App.

Comment: my email that i added does show up when i go on preferences then accounts but it does show up when i just go on accounts